# how to call sizeForItemAtIndexPath method after screen rotates

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have made my collection view cells to be calculated programmatically and I'm using `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` method to set the cell's sizes.

But When the screen rotates ,I need to recalculate the sizes and set them for cells. So,How can I call that function again after screen rotates?

By the way, I know `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` method and the only problem I got is that I don't know how should I call set the cell's sizes again.

Thanks

Comment: Reload your collectionview after orientation change.

Comment: This Question is Already ask.

Answer (score 4):

Another way using newer UIViewController methods

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
    [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context)
     {

     } completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context)
     {
         [self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
     }];

    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reload your collection view in this method: This method is called when device changes its orientation. Reload collectionview will call sizeForItemAtIndexPath.

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    [collectionView reloadData]; // change collectionView with your collection view
}
```

Comment: ,Is there any other better way?Because by calling reloadData lot's of methods would be called .I just need to call one method.Is that possible ?

Comment: if you are using autolayout then you can call. [self layoutIfNeeded].

Answer (score 0):

Calculating the dynamics of cell can be replaced with auto calculation.

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout *) self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout;
flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSizeMake(estimatedWidth, estimatedHeight)];
```

Comment: what does estimatedItemSize  do?I want to dislay two columns of cells on every screen size and orientations. Can this method do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    [collectionView reloadInputViews]; 
}
```